# Changing a value in datatable doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#

I have a problem in **datable**.

I get the result of a select query in datable.

I want to change the **date to Persian date** and it is work. But when I display this **datable** in **DataGridView** instead of showing `1392/02/11` it shows `1392/11/02` (change the place of month and day what should I do?)

```
DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
dtt = DataPortAction.GetCustomerHostById(CustomerId);

for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
    dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dtt.Rows[i][2]);
    System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pa = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
    string s = pa.GetYear(dt1) + "/" + pa.GetMonth(dt1) + "/" + pa.GetDayOfMonth(dt1);
    dtt.Rows[i][2] = s;
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
```

I change the place of Get Day and Get Month but it doesn't shown in DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dtt.Rows[i][2]);
```

You should use e.g.

```
dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dtt.Rows[i][2], "yyyy/dd/MM/", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or simply:

```
dt1 = dtt.Rows[i][2].ToString("yyyy/dd/MM/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your column type of your date in your datagridview and the datatable to string, as a result the display will not auto format the date when bound the table to the gridview.

The problem of your thing is auto formating when bound